# Store and reference a list of variables by name

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to create a library function to store pointers to variables of various types (int, char, String, etc.), and later print their value by referencing their name.

So:

```
int a;
const char *b;
String c;
storeVar("a", &a);
storeVar("b", &b);
storeVar("c", &c);
```

and later:

```
printVar("a");
printVar("b");
printVar("c");
```

The trick here is that I don't want to enumerate all potential types that might be called by users the library; that is, I'd like to use templates to generate the necessary code at compile time based on which types I'm using in the storeVar() calls.

I could solve this in a relatively straightforward (if clunky) manner if I enumerated all potential data types, either by using a union and a type enum, or by keeping separate lists of each variable by type... but I can't figure out how to solve it generically.

Any thoughts?  I'm working on an Arduino platform, so I'm more constrained than I would be on a PC (e.g. Boost probably isn't an option).

---

This solution, based on the code offered by Massimiliano Janes, is working.  Unfortunately, unordered_map is not available across the entire Arduino platform, so I may not be able to use it.  However, that's just a storage detail, and I am confident this approach will work regardless of how the variables are stored.

```
// rst.h
#include <unordered_map>    

class Rst {    

private:
    struct variable
    {
      virtual void print_me() const = 0;
    };    

    template<typename T>
    struct variable_of_type: variable
    {
      T *var;    

      variable_of_type(T *v) : var{v} { }    

      void print_me() const override { 
        Serial.println(*var); 
      }
    };    

public:    
    template<typename T>
    void store_var(const char *name, T *v) { 
        varList[name] = new variable_of_type<T>(v);
    }    

    void print(const char *name) {
        varList[name]->print_me();
    }    

private:
    std::unordered_map<const char*, variable*> varList;
};
```

---

```
#include "rst.h"    

Rst rst;    

int q;
int a = 0;
const char* b = "hallo";    

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);    

    Serial.println("=====");    

    rst.store_var("q", &q);    

    rst.store_var("a", &a);
    rst.store_var("b", &b);
    q = 10;
    rst.print("q");
    rst.print("a");
    rst.print("b");    

    q=15;
    rst.print("q");
}    

void loop() {
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to implement something similar like [`std::variant<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: "Generically" one might use something like `std::variant` (as mentioned) or [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Or their corresponding Arduino classes (if they exist). And if no corresponding Arduino-specific classes exist, and you can't use either the standard library or Boost, then you might have no choice but to use the "clunky" solution.

Comment: std::variant/any aren't available in the Arduino universe. unordered_map might be; I'll check that out

Comment: Ypur requirments give a strong vibe of a XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm working on a library where users can set or retrieve the values of variables by specifying their names over the serial port (or similar).  It's a library, so I don't know what types or names users will want to use, though I could limit it to numbers and strings.  I also don't need to worry about changing the list of available variables once the program is running.  Memory footprint is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost is mostly header only, so, unless your platform lacks language level support, boost variant/any/type-erasure/containers should work for you out of the box ...

Anyway, if you still want to write your own type-erasure solution, the idea is to incapsulate the 'generic' behaviour behind an abstract interface, and let the virtual dispatch mechanism invoke the actual, templated implementation, something like:

```
struct variable
{
  virtual ~variable() = default;
  virtual void print_me() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct variable_of_type:
  variable
{
  T const& var;

  variable_of_type(T const& v)
    :var{v}{}

  virtual void print_me() const override
    { std::cout << var << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
auto make_var(T const& v) // beware of v's lifetime !
  { return std::make_unique<variable_of_type<T>>(v); }

int main()
{
  auto a = 0;
  auto b = std::string{"hallo"};
  auto vars = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<variable>>{};

  vars["a"] = make_var(a);
  vars["b"] = make_var(b);
  vars["a"]->print_me();
  vars["b"]->print_me();
}
```

more precisely, a truly type-erased solution would hide the unique_ptr layer behind some *regular* type (eg. see `std::any`, `std::function<void()>`, ...), anyway, I hope you got the basic idea ...